# Accessing a nested structure slot

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following structures:

```
(defstruct track 
    size 
    env 
    startpos 
    endpositions)

(defstruct state 
    pos 
    vel
    action
    cost
    track
    other)
```

I have a state and Im trying to access endpositions(list of lists)

```
(setq coluna_final (nth 1 (nth 0 (state-track-endpositions st))))
```

but I get the error: `EVAL: undefined function STATE-TRACK-ENDPOSITIONS`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to use `car` or `first` instead of `nth 0` and `cadr` or `second` instead of `nth 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first [`defstruct`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm) defines (inter alia) function `track-endpositions`, and the second defines `state-track`. Lisp has no way to know that the latter returns a `track` (even if you declare the slot type, it will not define the function you want).

You can do it yourself:

```
(defun state-track-endpositions (st)
  (track-endpositions (state-track st)))
```